Is it possible to construct algebraic numbers from $\mathbb{Q}$ without using polynomials?
In $\mathbb{N}$, we can define an equivalence relation on the Cartesian product $\mathbb{N}^2$ as $(a,b) \sim (c,d)$ if and only if $a + d = b + c$. Then, the quotient set $\mathbb{N}^2 / \sim$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ (this is one way $\mathbb{Z}$ is defined in some books).
Similarly, there is an equivalence relation on the set of all Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb{Q}$, denoted $\mathbb{L}$, where $p_n \sim q_n$ if and only if $\lim_{n \to \infty}(p_n - q_n) = 0$. The quotient set $\mathbb{L} / \sim$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.
My question is: Is there an equivalence relation on the $n$-fold Cartesian product $\mathbb{Q}^n$ such that the quotient set $\mathbb{Q}^n / \sim$ is isomorphic to the algebraic numbers $\mathbb{A}$, which are the roots of polynomials with integer coefficients? (I believe $n$ can be finite because $\mathbb{A}$ is countable.)
Furthermore, can such an equivalence relation be defined by some binary operation as in the first example? If so, is this binary operation commutative and associative?
Clarification: By “isomorphic to,” I mean isomorphic as a group. My consideration is: Is there a binary operation on  $\mathbb{R}$  that makes  $\mathbb{A}$  the smallest field closed under this operation, similar to how  $\mathbb{Z}$  is closed under subtraction and  $\mathbb{R}$  is the closure under limits, so that I can naturally extend  $\mathbb{Q}$  into $\mathbb{A}$?

There's an issue here about what you mean by "isomorphic to". In both of your examples, the quotient sets are isomorphic to the structures after defining the operations of $+$ and $\times$ in some way. e.g. there is a natural bijection $\mathbb{N}^2/{\sim}\to \mathbb{Z}$, and there is a natural way to define operations on $\mathbb{N}^2/{\sim}$ in such a way that this bijection turns into an isomorphism of rings. So I think what you really want to ask is whether we can define operations on $\mathbb{Q}^n/{\sim}$ in such a way that it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}$.

"isomorphic" in what sense? As sets, you can even take $n=1$ and $\sim$ to be trivial; this is indeed just a statement of countability. If you mean as a group, then this is not possible, since $\mathbb A$ is infinite-dimensional over $\mathbb Q$.

But now to make the question non-trivial, you need to put some restriction on how you want the operations to be defined. After all, any countable set $X$ can be put in bijection with $\mathbb{A}$ (since $\mathbb{A}$ is countable), and this bijection can be turned into an isomorphism of rings by transferring the ring operations from $\mathbb{A}$ to $X$ along the isomorphism.

One way to make the question non-trivial is to ask whether the ring $\mathbb{A}$ is interpretable in the ring $\mathbb{Q}$ in the sense of first-order logic. But this might not be what you really intended to ask, since the construction of $\mathbb{R}$ from $\mathbb{Q}$ by Cauchy sequences is not a first-order interpretation.

@AlexKruckman I’ve tried to update the question based on your feedback. Please let me know if the clarification makes things clearer.

@Wojowu I’ve tried to update the question based on your feedback. Please let me know if the clarification makes things clearer.

Limits are not a binary operation, they are a partial function on infinitely many variables. So why not allow a multivalued function on finitely many variables, i.e. extracting roots of a polynomial from its coefficients, which $\mathbb A$ is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb R$ containing $\mathbb Q$ and closed under?

Of course the answer to your final question is positive in any case: Fix a bijection $f\colon \mathbb Q \to \mathbb A$ and consider the binary operation $(x,y) \mapsto f(x)$.

As a group, $\mathbb A$ is the same as $\mathbb Q^{(\omega)}$ (the direct sum of countably many copies of $\mathbb Q$). Thus, polynomials are irrelevant anyway.
